# .net 6 and OLEDB

Tags: oledb, .net-6.0

I have a program (.Net Framework 4.6) that reads and updates excel spreadsheet via OleDd.

I have ported this code to .Net 6 solution using the System.Data.OleDb (6.0.0) package.
It works fine on my development pc (Win 10), but when I upload it to deployment server (Windows server 2016) I get error:

> The data providers require Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC).
> Please install Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) version 2.6 or
> later.

The .Net Framework 4.6 app is working on the deployment server just fine.

I have installed:

- AccessDatabaseEngine2016.exe
- mdac28sdk.msi

My .Net 6 app is running in 32Bit mode

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

Regarding a .NET_6 project I'm working on under 64bit Visual Studio with C#, and which I was in_serious trouble with, well, reading your question text brought me to rebuild this project of mine now specifically for 32-bit instead of building for "Any". This solved my_pending problem to get OLE.DB successfully opening a_connection to M$Access, which had been installed as part of 32-bit M$Office. It was a relief to finally get across my OLE.DB hurdle this way (after a good number of hours), but in hindsight I am surprised that earlier on, with .Net Framework v4.8, I can't seem to have needed this sort of bitwise accuracy.
So for what it's worth, at least in my case bitlevels were essential and crucial to get OLE.DB working under .NET_6.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).